# Reflecting a graph created via LayeredDigraphEmbedding

Tags: graphs-and-networks

ETA: I use LayeredDigraphEmbedding, oriented towards the bottom so that the directed graph displays with the arrows pointing upwards (they serve as Hasse diagrams which is why the orientation is used).

Layered embedding seems to layer the vertices in right to left order rather than left to right order. Is there a way to reverse this. I added this comment as it seems this may be the cause of the issue described below (?).

The vertices for a graph are represented by hourglass as follows:

```
vf[{xc_, yc_}, name_, {w_, h_}] := 
  Block[{xmin = xc - w, xmax = xc + w, ymin = yc - h, ymax = yc + h}, 
   Polygon[{{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}, {xmin, ymax}, {xmax, ymin}}]];
```

I work with the graph:

```
g = 
  Graph[{1, 2, 3, 4}, {DirectedEdge[1, 3], DirectedEdge[1, 4], 
    DirectedEdge[2, 3], 
    DirectedEdge[2, 4]}, {FormatType -> TraditionalForm, 
    GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", 
      "Orientation" -> Bottom}, ImageSize -> {240, 240}, 
    VertexLabels -> {3 -> 
       Placed[{Style[3, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
         Style[3, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]}, {Before, After}], 
      4 -> Placed[{Style[4, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
         Style[1, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]}, {Before, After}], 
      2 -> Placed[{Style[2, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
         Style[2, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]}, {Before, After}], 
      1 -> Placed[{Style[1, RGBColor[1, 0, 0]], 
         Style[4, RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]}, {Before, After}]}, 
    VertexShapeFunction -> {vf}, VertexWeight -> {1, 2, 3, 4}}]
```

It displays as follows:

[image]

I need it to be displayed so the red 1 and 3 occur on the left and the red 2 and 4 occur on the right. I considered ReflectionTransform with respect to {1,0} but could not get it to work. Is there a way to reflect the graph with respect to its central vertical axis so it displays correctly? Or can LayeredDigraphEmbedding in the code be adjusted to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to have some automatic way of achieving this? Otherwise, just swap ``Before`` and ``After`` in the appropriate labels.

Comment: Your code does not work with `FullForm` included in the definition of `g`. If you want to look at the `FullForm`, use parentheses to isolate the `FullForm` from the definition, i.e., `(g = ...) // FullForm`

Comment: @BobHanlon I removed the FullForm part. I only used it to display the code from a figure obtained by other code. Should be fine now.

Comment: @Domen I need it to be automatic.

Comment: @Michel maybe GraphLayout -> {"LayeredDigraphEmbedding", "RootVertex" -> {3, 4}}?

Comment: Thanks @halmir. I need a solution that works on all the examples. All it needs is to be reflected over its central vertical axis. The layering puts nodes on the same level, but does not respect their enumeration.

Comment: @kglr I wonder if you might have advice: the bottom orientation for LayeredGraphEmbedding causes the vertices in the layers to be displayed right to left rather than left-to-right. Is there a way to keep the bottom orientation but display the vertices in left-to-right order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertex coordinate transformations are easy with `IGVertexMap` from IGraph/M:

```
IGVertexMap[{-1, 1} # &, VertexCoordinates, g]
```

[image]

Or use `IGVertexMap[ReflectionTransform[{1, 0}], VertexCoordinates, g]` if you like. Or rotate by 30 degrees, `IGVertexMap[RotationTransform[30 Degree], VertexCoordinates, g]`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.